# Word count using Hive

Tags: count, hive, hdfs, hql

Lets say I have a table with columns id and content:

```
id | content
________________________
1  | abc abr abc as abs
2  | abc arc cre arc
3  | agr ann agd agd agd
```

What I want is output like this:

```
{"abc":2,"abr":1,"as":1, "abs":1}  # for id 1
{"abc":1,"arc":2,"cre":1}          # for id 2
{"agr":1,"agd":3,"ann":1}          # for id 3
```

How could the task be done using Hive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need [this](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse) library.  It's pretty straightforward to build.

**Query**:

```
ADD JAR /path/to/jar/brickhouse-0.7.1.jar;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION COLLECT AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';

SELECT id
  , COLLECT(words, c) AS count_map
FROM (
  SELECT id
    , words
    , COUNT(*) AS c
  FROM (
    SELECT id, words
    FROM db.tbl
    LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(SPLIT(content, ' ')) exptbl AS words ) x
  GROUP BY id, words ) y
GROUP BY id
```

**Output**:

```
+----+---------------------------------+
|id  |count_map                        |
+----+---------------------------------+
|1   |{"as":1,"abs":1,"abc":2,"abr":1} |
+----+---------------------------------+
|2   |{"cre":1,"arc":2,"abc":1}        |
+----+---------------------------------+
|3   |{"ann":1,"agr":1,"agd":3}        |
+----+---------------------------------+
```